# Why do some parents prefer some children more than others?

Tags: emotion, parenting, love

Is it true that parents tend to love or have a higher preference for some particular children of theirs?

If so, why?

Have any studies stated which of their children they love or prefer more?

Comment: I bet a question like this would make a big splash over at [parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) too! I'd hate to migrate it away from us, but maybe cross-posting would be forgivable (especially if you don't get caught). I could rephrase and cross-post (and destroy the evidence that I thought of it, i.e., this comment!) on your behalf to help in that endeavor if you like.

Comment: Sure, just link it back here so that the psychological aspect of this could also be studied. [Cross-posting is not always bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/221866) and in this case it would be good to cross post over to [parenting.se].

Comment: I see! I've taken note of their [guidelines for on-topic questions](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the recommendations from Meta SO. I'm going the above-board route, linking everything, and paraphrasing to minimize overlap in the scope of desirable answers. I guess you [wouldn't really call this paraphrasing though](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11283/6389), would you...

Comment: Just earned a "nice question" badge over there. I thought it'd go over well (eventually)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is quite a lot of research on [parental favoritism](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=parental%20favoritism). I'll summarize some of the findings:

- girls are more often parental favorites (Harris & Howard, 1985)
- women more often report parental favoritism (Chalfant, 1994)
- parents favor less aggressive children (which partially explains their preference for girls; Tucker et al., 2003)
- the youngest child is more often the parental favorite (Harris & Howard, 1985; Rhode et al., 2003; Tucker et al., 2003)
- the middle child is least often the parental favorite (Harris & Howard, 1985; Hertwig et al., 2002)
- 19% of 1st-born siblings, 30% of middle-born, and 26% of last-born claimed to be their father's favorite (Chalfant, 1994)
- 23% of 1st-born, 10% of middle-born, and 28% of last-born siblings claimed to be their mother's favorite (Chalfant, 1994)
- favoritism was most often reported from a parent of the opposite sex (Chalfant, 1994)
- only about 10% of children and 10% of parents felt or admitted that they had been favored or favored a child (Bedford, 1992)
- more than 75% of the siblings felt themselves to be the favorite of at least one of their parents (Kiracofe & Kiracofe, 1990)

As you can see, findings are somewhat contradictory.

Parental favoritism has consequences:

- Self-esteem in the child correlates to perceived parental favoritism (Felson & Zielinski, 1989; Zervas & Sherman, 1994). Children, whose parents had treated all children equally, rated highest in self-esteem; favored children rated lower, nonfavored lowest (Zervas & Sherman, 1994). Parents' supportive behavior affects the self-esteem of children but child self-esteem also affects how much support children report their parents give them; in addition, parents have a greater effect on the self-esteem of girls than of boys (Felson & Zielinski, 1989).
- Siblings express less warmth and greater hostility toward one another when parents show favoritism (McHale et al., 1995)
- over time, being unfavored by parents produces behavior problems in children (Richmond, Stocker, & Rienks, 2005)

Explanations for parental favoritism include:

- Stress predicts favoritism. Favoritism is more common when parents experience marital problems and when children have serious health problems (Singer & Weinstein, 2000).
- Personality of the child predicts favoritism (see e.g. aggression above).

There is research on favoritism of children for parent also, as well as favoritism of adult children, both of which I did not report.

All of the above is limted to Western cultures. As we know, there are some cultures where parents go so far in their favoritism that they *kill* female children. The conclusion is that favoritism is not universal but culture specific.

---

*Note:* Most of the text above is copy/pasted directly from the quoted papers. I did not mark it as quotes as this would have greatly reduced readability.

**Sources**

- Bedford, V. H. (1992). Memories of parental favoritism and the quality of parent-child ties in adulthood. Journal of Gerontology, 47(4), S149-S155.
- Chalfant, D. (1994). Birth order, perceived parental favoritism, and feelings toward parents. Individual Psychology: Journal of Adlerian Theory, Research & Practice.
- Felson, R. B., & Zielinski, M. A. (1989). Children's self-esteem and parental support. Journal of Marriage and the Family, 727-735.
- Harris, I. D., & Howard, K. I. (1985). Correlates of perceived parental favoritism. The Journal of genetic psychology, 146(1), 45-56.
- Hertwig R., Davis J.N., & Sulloway F.J. (2002). Parental investment: How an equity motive can produce inequality. Psychological Bulletin, 128, 728–745.
- Kiracofe, N. M., & Kiracofe, H. N. (1990). Child-perceived parental favoritism and birth order. Individual Psychology: Journal of Adlerian Theory, Research & Practice.
- McHale S.M., Crouter A.C., McGuire S.A., & Updegraff K.A. (1995). Congruence between mothers' and fathers' differential treatment of siblings: Links with family relations and children's well-being. Child Development, 66, 116–128.
- Richmond M.K., Stocker C.M., & Rienks S.L. (2005). Longitudinal associations between sibling relationship quality, parental differential treatment, and children's adjustment. Journal of Family Psychology, 19, 550–559.
- Rohde, P. A., Atzwanger, K., Butovskaya, M., Lampert, A., Mysterud, I., Sanchez-Andres, A., & Sulloway, F. J. (2003). Perceived parental favoritism, closeness to kin, and the rebel of the family: The effects of birth order and sex. Evolution and Human Behavior, 24(4), 261-276.
- Tucker C.J., McHale S.M., & Crouter A.C. (2003). Dimensions of mothers' and fathers' differential treatment of siblings: Links with adolescents' sex-typed personal qualities. Family Relations, 52, 82–89.
- Zervas, L. J., & Sherman, M. F. (1994). The relationship between perceived parental favoritism and self-esteem. The Journal of genetic psychology, 155(1), 25-33.